# How to structure data correctly for ML models to interpret it

Tags: python, keras, computer-vision, handwriting-recognition

I have separated my entire data into various folders for different classes for hand digit recognition. How do I let my model know that a certain class A contains images depicting the letter *A*.

Answer (score 1):

```
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1.0 / 255, shear_range=0.2, zoom_range=0.2, horizontal_flip=True
)
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        "Image Folder/", target_size=(28, 28), batch_size=1, class_mode="binary"
    )
print(train_generator[0])
```

In the example above `Image folder` must have sub-folders for each class like below:

- some/path/

  - class1/

    - image1.jpg
    - image2.jpg
  - class2/

    - image3.jpg
    - etc
  - etc

Comment: thank you very much! so the class name should have the same name with that of the character it is representing right? for example, if the folder contains latter A the folder name should be " A" right?

Comment: @soldour Keras assumes that images are stored in a folder tree with one separate subfolder per class. So you have to name the folder as well as the class name.